# Python. import с одного модуля в другой

Tags: python, package

Создал **пакет pack** и в пакете следующие файлы (прикрепил изображение)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Почему не ставится **"точка"** при импорте внутренних пакетов в модуль **main.py**. А при импорте в модуль **doctors.py** ставится?

```
# Модуль main в пакете pack
    from hospital.doctors import get_doctors

    get_doctors()
```

from "**нету точки**"hospital.doctors import get_doctors

```
# Модуль doctors в пакете hospital
    from .patients.died_people import get_alive

    def get_doctors():
        get_alive()
        print("Doctors from hospital package")
```

from "**точка**"patients.died_people import get_alive

```
# Модуль dead_people в пакете patients
    def get_alive():
        print("Dead people from patients package")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При импорте в main используется абсолютный импорт, а при doctors относительный.

При абсолютном импорте используется полный путь (от начала корневой папки проекта) к желаемому модулю.

При относительном импорте используется относительный путь (начиная с пути текущего модуля) к желаемому модулю.

Вот ссылка на статью там всё написано.
https://tproger.ru/translations/guide-into-python-imports/